# What does this Scheme code mean? (Definition of 'list' operator using lambda)

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

As the definition to the list operator that compiles and returns a list of arguments , i found this scheme code at [this tutorial](http://cs.hut.fi/Studies/T-93.210/schemetutorial/node4.html#SECTION00440000000000000000)

```
(define list
(lambda args args))
```

But, This doesn't match with the usual lambda syntax that i know. I mean, the lambda should have the parameters in brackets etc. Please explain how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the general form of arguments in a lambda seems to always include parentheses, it's not necessarily required. If take a look at [this section](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/start.html#./start:h5) in the [The Scheme Programming Language 4e](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/), it says that:

> The general form of lambda is a bit more complicated than the form we saw earlier, in that **the formal parameter specification, (var ...), need not be a proper list, or indeed even a list at all**. The formal parameter specification can be in any of the following three forms:
>
> 1. a proper list of variables, (var1 ... varn), such as we have already seen,
> 2. a single variable, var<sub>n</sub>, or
> 3. an improper list of variables, (var1 ... varn . varr).
>
> In the first case, exactly n actual parameters must be supplied, and each variable is bound to the corresponding actual parameter. **In the second, any number of actual parameters is valid; all of the actual parameters are put into a single list and the single variable is bound to this list.**

The part in bold face (bold-face set by me), is the part that is very relevant to your question. And as your tutorial says, it is a varargs argument that is converted into a list.

Answer (score 3):

This defines a *variadic procedure* (a procedure that can take different numbers of arguments) of at least zero arguments. All the arguments are bundled up into a list called `args`, in this case.

Here's another example of a variadic procedure (this one requires at least one argument), which returns the minimum value of all the arguments passed in:

```
(define (min arg1 . rest)
  (let loop ((val arg1)
             (rest rest))
    (if (null? rest)
        val
        (let ((next (car rest)))
          (loop (if (< next val) next val)
                (cdr rest))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

A Scheme interpretation pairs up a formal parameter specification with the actual arguments supplied in a function call, thus doing a sort of restricted pattern matching, with the formal parameter specification serving as kind of a pattern.

When it is a proper list of length `n`, this is like saying, *will bind each of the `n` supplied argument values to each of the variables in the spec*. Scheme demands exactly `n` arguments be supplied in such situation, although some dialects could be imagined to allow more, or less, than `n` arguments in such function call, without causing an error:

```
(define mylist (lambda (x y)      ; (define (mylist x y)    ; exactly two 
  (list x y)))                    ;   (list x y))           ;  arguments required
```

When it's an improper list with `n` variables and one tail variable, this is like saying *if given more than `n` arguments, will bind the rest of them, as a list, to that tail variable*. If there were no more arguments, naturally an empty list will be bound to the tail variable:

```
(define mylist (lambda (x . y)    ; (define (mylist x . y)  ; at least one
  (cons x y)))                    ;   (cons x y))           ;  argument required
```

The sole variable as a formal parameter specifiction is identified as a tail variable of an improper list, serving as a particular variant of the previous case. It will be thus bound to all the argument values supplied in a function call, as a list:

```
(define mylist (lambda x          ; (define (mylist . x)    ; any number of
  x))                             ;   x)                    ;  arguments can be used
```

`x` is already a list holding all the supplied arguments.

As is readily seen, all three cases can be handled by the same code transformation,

```
(define (translate-define-to-lambda code)
  (list (car code)                 ; "define"
        (caadr code)               ; name
        (cons 'lambda
              (cons (cdadr code)   ; parameters
                    (cddr code)))))
```

(because `(cdr '(<a> . <b>))` == `<b>`).